# Listbox error C#

Tags: c#, listbox

now I have a listbox I need to add in it name of day and time and the program read each item in listbox auto and if the first item = my pc day and time show message and so on...
But I got dat error when the program reach the last item give me that error
And when I click on start button it doesnot wait until the first item = my pc day and time it go on the each item until reach the last give me that error

Note: When i use the below codes in VB its Working Fine Due To That Code
'On error Resum Next' So its fine, but in C# i cannot put that code so there are a Equivalent Of 'On Error Resume Next' ? To Solve this Problem

[Error Photo Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77wZM.png)

But It work in visual basic 100%

In button add items to listbox code:

```
Listbox5.items.add(textbox1.text + textbox2.text)
Listbox5.selectedindex=0
```

in Button1 start timer code:

```
timer1.enabled=true;
```

in Timer1 code:

```
  if (listbox5.text= datetime.now.tostring("ddd") +datetime.now.tolongtime())
  Messagebox.show("done")
  Listbox.selectedindex +=1
```

Comment: you have to check befor if the listbox contains enough elements

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you are only adding item to the ListBox but then you are incrementing the SelectedIndex to an index which doesn't exist.

Remove `Listbox.selectedindex +=1` OR add something new to the listbox before incrementing the selected index to resolve the error.

Comment: Removing it doesn't help if he actually wants to increment it. However checking if there're enough items does.

Comment: His comment is not very clear in regards to what he wants to do so I didn't assume anything. He is incrementing the index before adding anything to it.

Comment: I agree with that it's not clear. But since he does it we must assume that there's a reason behind it. And if that is to for example visually cycle through the ListBox, removing it won't help. That's why I think one should suggest change up front and not removal (unless keeping it can cause serious issues).

Comment: HeyGuys, the user will add item to listbox from button and i need when the user click on button start the program read each item in listbox as day ant time and if the first item = pc day and time show a message an so on iam Already added an items to listbox

Comment: Guys the mistake is when i try above codes in VB it's Working Due To Dat Code.. 'On Error Resume Next' But in C# iam not  Write this Code Cuz it's impossible So i got dat errros there are a Equivalent Of 'On Error Resume Next' ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not following what your code is actually trying to do but the problem would be setting SelectedIndex to a value that's higher than the max index in the ListBox.

You probably want something like this ...

```
if (listbox5.text= datetime.now.tostring("ddd") +datetime.now.tolongtime())
{
    Messagebox.show("done")
    //I'm guessing you would want to disable the timer here
}
else
{
    if (Listbox.SelectedIndex < (Listbox.Itmes.Count - 1))
    {
        Listbox.SelectedIndex +=1
    }
    else
    {
        //No more items to check so probably need to disable timer and do something else
    }
}
```